# C - read text into char array and print issue

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am reading text file (.txt) and getting values inside of it.

Here is my code:

```
// Definitions.
FILE* file;
date t1, calc[99999];
int index = 0, counter = 0, i;
char info[100];
char *newInfo[9999];

while(!feof(file)){
                fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %d\n", info, &t1.day, &t1.month, &t1.year);
                newInfo[index] = info;
                calc[index].day = t1.day;
                calc[index].month = t1.month;
                calc[index].year = t1.year;
                printf("read: %s %d %d %d\n", info, t1.day, t1.month, t1.year);
                index++;
                counter++;
        }
```

The result is:

```
line_1 01 01 2011
line_2 02 02 2012
line_3 03 03 2013
```

It is okay so far but when I try to print them out of while loop, it always prints last value which is `line_3`.

```
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
printf("%s %d %d %d\n", newInfo[i], calc[i].day, calc[i].month, calc[i].year);
```

Result is:

```
line_3 01 01 2011
line_3 02 02 2012
line_3 03 03 2013
```

It is supposed to print result as I expected (which I showed above).

I am making assignment at `newInfo[index] = info;` line and increasing `index` variable. But it still shows me only latest text.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Close to duplicates of this problem have been asked a number of times before.  The difficulty, as ever, is identifying the question it is a duplicate of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A wise man once lamented, `"What has been will be again, what has been done will be done again; there is nothing new under the sun."`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, some high percentage of questions in the language tags involve the same 15 or 20 of issues e.g. eof in a loop, operations on a read-only string, unallocated space for ptrs, etc.  It would be nice, possibly even a substantial value, if there was a mechanism to abstract those issues out under their own sub-tags.  This would reduce the problems of duplicates by not labeling them duplicates.  They are merely examples in the corpus of the sub-tag.  The goal is not to weed them out but properly categorize them.

Comment: @Duck: In general terms, a good idea, but not all that easy to implement. One problem is deciding on suitable tag names; another is finding the questions to put the tag on; another is choosing the canonical question and answer. I've started a minor collection of what I consider canonical Q&A examples for some questions (`while (!feof(fp))`, for example).  But I've not gone out of my way to create good tags and tag questions where that's an issue.  (That particular issue is seldom the only problem with the code; it is usually just one additional problem of the many.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I completely agree that the multiple problem questions are vexing.  For sub-tag categories I would suggest that creation be limited to and voted upon by people who have earned a badge in a language tag.  Presumably this confers both a degree of competence with the tag area and an ongoing familiarity with categories of questions asked.  I am surprised, for instance, how readily (and accurately) people have come to recognize XY problems.  If sub-tags are kept to a manageable set I think the same recognition would kick in.  In any case, probably a Meta discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are not first-class objects -- they're just a special case of arrays, which themselves are just a special case of pointers.  One of the consquences of this is that operations such as assignment don't work as you'd expect.  The line

```
newInfo[index] = info;
```

isn't copying the string "info", it's copying the underlying pointer.  In order to copy a string, you need to use "strcpy()" (if you've already allocated space for the string), or "strdup()" if you haven't (and then you need to remember to free the memory allocated).  In your code, you would replace the above line with

```
newInfo[index] = strdup(info);
```

Answer (score 4):

`newinfo` is an array of ptrs.  Each of those pointers is set to point to `info`.  `info` is going to hold the last thing it read so, consequently every pointer in `newinfo` is going to point to the last thing read.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you save the info into the same array each time, copying the pointer (start of array)  represented by `info` to `NewInfo[index]`, which doesn't help.

You have to allocate space for the string to go in, and assign that to `NewInfo[index]`.  Simplest, if your system has it, is:

```
NewInfo[index] = strdup(info);
```